# What is jQueryMobile Panel widget in DojoMobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, dojo

Is there a widget in DojoMobile that looks like Panels in jQuery Mobile ?

In jQuery Mobile, it' something like this : http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_panels.asp

I found this with Dojo http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/fx/wipeIn.html but I don't know if it suits with Mobile.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look at all the demo for dojo mobile:

[Dojo Mobile Widgets](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo-iphone.html)

The Lists do something similar to what you want.  Also, check out Accordian